# How to rectify the error ADD failes: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore in the Docker file?

Tags: dockerfile, github-actions, pipeline, cicd, docker-build

I am getting an error even after doing a lot of adjustments. The error is as follows -

> ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat prise/target/prise-8.18.0-
> SNAPSHOT-app.jar: file does not exist
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

My docker file is as follows -

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim

ADD prise/target/prise-8.18.0-SNAPSHOT-app.jar app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

# Run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

My CI CD github actions are as follows -

```
name: Build Maven artefacts and publish Docker image

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ] 
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: abc/prise
  
jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    
    - name: Standard Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Package artefact
      run: mvn --batch-mode clean install -DskipTests -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dsurefire.failIfNoSpecifiedTests=false
    
    - name: Package Maven artefacts
      run: mvn -B package -DskipTests --file pom.xml
    
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build .. --file Dockerfile
```

In the pom.xml a spring boot runnable jar is created. That means after we create a jar file of the *prise* application, a spring boot runnable jar file is also created which is named as *prise-8.18.0-SNAPSHOT-app.jar* . The pom.xml is as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.prise</groupId>
  <artifactId>prise-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.13.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Preis project</name>
  <description>Module project</description>
  <inceptionYear>2014</inceptionYear>
  <modules>
    <module>prise-module1</module>
    <module>prise</module>
  </modules>
  <properties>
    <spring-boot.app-classifier>app</spring-boot.app-classifier>
    <spring-boot.app-jar>${project.build.finalName}-${spring-boot.app-classifier}.jar</spring-boot.app-jar>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    .....
    <!--other dependency versions-->
    .....
   </properties>
```

I thought that the error is because of the single dot in the docker build line. As it indicates the relative path. However, similar error was generated when I added double dot after the build. The console log of the github actions for maven package and clean/install also looks ok as bothe jar files are created int he process. I do not understand why the error is still there.

```
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build . --file Dockerfile
```

Comment: Remove the second checkout step before `docker build` and change the first checkout to `actions/checkout@v3` instead of `@v2`.

Comment: The second checkout checks out your repo again and `cd` into its directory where the built file is not present because it's now one level higher up the tree.